# How can I get an audiosessionId from Exoplayer?

Tags: android, media, exoplayer

I'm trying to use Exoplayer in my project (instead of the MediaPlayer of Android). However, I have a problem: getting the id of current audio session. With traditional MediaPlayer, it's easy by calling getAudioSessionId, but Exoplayer hasn't any corresponding method. Anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

As of ExoPlayer2 `MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer` and `PlayerControl` can't be used anymore to obtain the AudioSessionId. Instead, you should set an <strike>`AudioRendererEventListener`</strike> on your exoPlayer instance.

---

**EDIT:**

`AudioRendererEventListener` is now deprecated. Use `AnalyticsListener` instead.

```
exoplayer.addAnalyticsListener(new AnalyticsListener() {
    /**
     * Called when the audio session id is set.
     *
     * @param eventTime      The event time.
     * @param audioSessionId The audio session id.
     */
    @Override
    public void onAudioSessionId(EventTime eventTime, int audioSessionId) {
         // do something with audioSessionId
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Player.AudioComponent audioComponent = exoPlayer.getAudioComponent();
int audioSessionid=audioComponent.getAudioSessionId();
```

exoplayer mod by me in [github](https://github.com/i4nnet/mod-exoplayer.git)

Answer (score 1):

```
  import  com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PlayerControl;
```

Instantiate PlayerControl object by passing your Exoplayer instance. and call getAudioSessionId.

```
PlayerControl playerControl=new PlayerControl(Exoplayer.instance);

int audioSessionId=playerControl.getAudioSessionId();
```

I think this is what you wants.

Comment: PlayerControl don't support this method, but I've found solution. I use onAudioSessionId of Render class.

Comment: Oooo....would be better if you could post a simple implementation example for other visitors

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet that i used to fetch audio session id -

```
  FrameworkSampleSource sampleSource = new FrameworkSampleSource(getApplicationContext(), builtUri, null);
  MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT){
        @Override
        protected void onAudioSessionId(int audioSessionId) {

            // do whatever u want to do with id.
        }
    };

   exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
   exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple answer among all above:

```
int audioSessionId = exoPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
```

This gives the audio session id of currently playing media.